# Making 10 it write 1.0*10 with javascript

Tags: javascript

In this code that I wrote I want to show the words like this :
if we put 10000 it write 1.0*10<sup>4</sup>
but it is not working.
In this code, we  write the number to the input file and after that we should click on the button it must show us the new number with that kind of thing.
but this code has a problem but I don't know where is it.
How can I solve the problem?

```js
function check() {
  var K = 9 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10;
  var q1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
  var q2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;
  var r = document.getElementById('r').value;
  var F = K * (q1 * q2) / (r * r);

  if (F >= 0) || (F <= 9) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F;
  }
  if
  else(F >= 10) || (F <= 99) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 10 + " * 10";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 100) || (F <= 999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 100 + " * 10<sup>2</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 1000) || (F <= 9999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 1000 + " * 10<sup>3</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 10000) || (F <= 99999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 10000 + " * 10<sup>4</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 100000) || (F <= 999999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 100000 + " * 10<sup>5</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 1000000) || (F <= 9999999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 1000000 + " * 10<sup>6</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 10000000) || (F <= 99999999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 10000000 + " * 10<sup>7</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 100000000) || (F <= 999999999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 100000000 + " * 10<sup>8</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 1000000000) || (F <= 9999999999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 1000000000 + " * 10<sup>9</sup>";
  }
  if
  else(F >= 10000000000) || (F <= 99999999999) {
    document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F / 10000000000 + " * 10<sup>10</sup>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="q1" placeholder="q1">
<input type="text" id="q2" placeholder="q2">
<input type="text" id="r" placeholder="r">
<input type="submit" onClick="check()">
<p id="end2"></p>
```

Comment: maybe you have a look to writing with exponents of 10, like `1.234E3` for `1234`.

Comment: Your code has a number of syntax errors. `if` demands parentheses around the _entire_ condition. And it's `else if`, not `if else`.

Comment: Once that's settled, you will be faced with logical errors. Basically, every `||` you wrote should be replaced by `&&`.

Comment: By the way, your code seems to assume `F` is integer, which is hardly realistic considering `F = K*(q1*q2)/(r*r)`. You will see no output if F happens to be 9.5 or 99.5 or 999.5...

Comment: @ruud-helderman so what should I do?

Comment: That's not up to me to decide; what do _you_ think should happen when F happens to be 9.5? What kind of output do you expect? What will you do to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your codes:

```
if else(F>=10)||(F<=99) {
//...
}
```

is

```
else if ( F>=10 || F<=99 ) {
//...
}
```

since the statement is

```
if( conditionA ) {
// block
}
else if( conditionB ) {
 // block
}
else {
 // block
}
```

It's not clear from your question which is the right output, by the way this is the working code (correct syntax):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
   function check()
   {
    var K = 9*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10;
    var q1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
    var q2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;
    var r = document.getElementById('r').value;
    var F = K*(q1*q2)/(r*r);
    
    if(F>=0&&F<=9){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = F;
    }
    else if(F>=10&&F<=99){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/10) + " * 10";
    }
    else if(F>=100&&F<=999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/100) + " * 10<sup>2</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=1000&&F<=9999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/1000) + " * 10<sup>3</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=10000&&F<=99999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/10000) + " * 10<sup>4</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=100000&&F<=999999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/100000) + " * 10<sup>5</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=1000000&&F<=9999999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/1000000) + " * 10<sup>6</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=10000000&&F<=99999999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/10000000) + " * 10<sup>7</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=100000000&&F<=999999999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/100000000) + " * 10<sup>8</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=1000000000&&F<=9999999999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/1000000000) + " * 10<sup>9</sup>";
    }
    else if(F>=10000000000&&F<=99999999999){
     document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = parseFloat(F/10000000000) + " * 10<sup>10</sup>";
    }
   }

  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  
  
  <input type="text" id="q1" placeholder="q1">
  <input type="text" id="q2" placeholder="q2">
  <input type="text" id="r" placeholder="r">
  <input type="submit" onclick="check()">
  <p id="end2"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

By the way I suggest to you this solution that avoid all the checks and makes use of `toExponential()` function:

```
var q1=3,q2=4,r=2;
var K = 9*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10;
var F = K*(q1*q2)/(r*r);
F.toExponential()
```

```js
var q1 = 3,
  q2 = 4,
  r = 2;
var K = 9 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 10;
var F = K * (q1 * q2) / (r * r);
//2.7 * 10<sup>9</sup>
var exponential = F.toExponential();
var base=parseFloat( exponential.split('e')[0] )
var exponent=parseInt( exponential.split('e')[1] )
console.log("%f * 10<sup>%f</sup>",base,exponent)
```

Comment: for example if you put 3 and 4 and 2 in the inputs then click the button it will show you :27000000000

Comment: But it must be 2.7 * 10<sup>9</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving this without writing so many conditions would be using toExponential() method, which returns a string with scientific notation. And then use replace() method to replace the 'e' character.

```
function check()
        {
            var K = 9*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10;
            var q1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
            var q2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;
            var r = document.getElementById('r').value;
            var F = K*(q1*q2)/(r*r);

            var num = F;
            var n = num.toExponential();
            n = n.replace(/e\+/g, '*10<sup>');
            n = n.replace(/e\-/g, '*10<sup>-');
            n+='</sup>';

            document.getElementById('end2').innerHTML = n;
        }
```